# Changing Windows Server 2008 password policy for a standalone server

Tags: windows-server-2008, password

How do you disable the password complexity requirements on a W2k8 server that is *not* part of an Active Directory?

I'd like to find the method that requires the fewest clicks and if there is any way to achieve this straight from the installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start > Run > gpedit.msc

From there: Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Account Policies > Password Policy

Comment: I guess you meant

Computer Configuration > **Windows Settings** > Security Settings > Account Policies > Password Policy > "Password must meet complexity requirements"

Comment: You guessed correctly. Glad you managed to find it.